# How to convert the VBScript code to Java as VB Script is supproted in Tridion SP1?

Tags: java, vbscript, tridion

We are migrating VBScript code to Java as VBScript is not supported in Tridion SP1. How to convert the below VBScript code to Java?

```
[%
   For Each lObjCP In Page.ComponentPresentations
       WriteOut lObjCP.Content
   Next
%]
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are referring to Tridion 2011 SP1? First of all, this version DOES support vbscript. Second, java is not a supported template language at all.

Comment: +1 to Quirijn, Vbscript is supported (but now "legacy"). Maybe this is Java in delivery (CD API)? Modular Templating would be the right templating path, though.

Answer (score 1):

Quirijn is correct. VBScript is supported by all current versions of Tridion. Secondly - Java would not be a good choice to port templating code to.